# Append object to a table template using jQuery Template

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I got this object

```
var data = [
{
    "cedula": "v-12334445",
    "nombres": "ALECIO NORBES EDUARDO RAMON",
    "id_school": "5"
},
{
    "cedula": "v-17322147",
    "nombres": "RAMIREZ CARRERO JOSE GERONIMO",
    "id_school": "1"
}
```

];

I'm using jQuery templates to render this data to a table, I got the table template into a var like this:

```
var reset_config_form = "<div>\
                      <table id='reset_user_template' class='table table-bordered'>\
                        <thead>\
                          <tr>\
                            <th><a>cédula</a></th>\
                            <th><a>nombres</a></th>\
                            <th><a>escuela</a></th>\
                            <th><a>acciones</a></th>\
                          </tr>\
                        </thead>\
                        <tbody>\
                        </tbody>\
                      </table>\
                      </div>";
```

And the row template as follows:

```
var reset_config_form_rows = "<tr>\
                                 {{each d}}\
                                  <td>${cedula}</td>\
                                  <td>${nombres}</td>\
                                  <td>${id_school}</td>\
                                  <td id='acciones'></td>\
                                {{/each}}\
                              </tr>";
```

In order to render the data I'm rendering the template with:

```
$(reset_config_form_rows).tmpl(d).appendTo('#reset_user_template');
```

I'm getting the data in one row, the each is not working.

[image]

The generated html

[image]

Comment: What about generated html? Have you looked it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because your loop is around your `TD` not your `TR`. Thats why you're seeing your columns duplicating.

Try this

```
var reset_config_form_rows = "{{each d}}\
                                 <tr>\
                                  <td>${cedula}</td>\
                                  <td>${nombres}</td>\
                                  <td>${id_school}</td>\
                                  <td id='acciones'></td>\
                                </tr>\
                              {{/each}}";
```